# Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview

I am getting this error when I try to add a search text box for my CertificateID column. I know it's becuase you can't use the "like" operation since my CertificateID column is int32 not a string. I just don't know what the code should be to make it work. I have tried Cast() function but haven't had any luck. could someone please help me with the code.
I am using the filterexpression to filter my data:

```
FilterExpression="[CertificateID] like '{0}%' and [Customs_Entry] like '{0}%' and [Product_Number] like '{1}%' and [Product_Name] like '{2}%'">

<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtCertificateID_Filter" Name="CertificateID" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
```

My full html is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

        <asp:Label ID="CertificateID_Label" runat="server" Width="169px">Certificate Number</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCertificateID_Filter" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Customs_Entry_Label" runat="server" Width="169px">Customs Entry Number</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustoms_Entry_Filter" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Product_Number_Label" runat="server" Width="169px">Product Number</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProduct_Number_Filter" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Customs_Name_Label" runat="server" Width="169px">Product Name</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProduct_Name_Filter" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" /> 
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="Certificate" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CertificateID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ShowFooter="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="AddRow" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Add" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CertificateID" HeaderText="Certificate Number" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CertificateID" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customs Entry" SortExpression="Customs_Entry">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Customs_Entry")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCustoms_Entry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Customs_Entry")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Certificate" SortExpression="Date_Certificate">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Certificate")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate_Certificate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Certificate")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Invoice Number" SortExpression="Invoice_Number">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Invoice_Number")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtInvoice_Number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Invoice_Number")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Number" SortExpression="Product_Number">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Product_Number")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProduct_Number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Product_Number")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name" SortExpression="Product_Name">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Product_Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProduct_Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Product_Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Category" SortExpression="Product_Category">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Product_Category") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GreatGrizzlyConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Category]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="txtProduct_Category" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GreatGrizzlyConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Category]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Product_Category")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CPSC Regulation" SortExpression="CPSC_Regulation">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CPSC_Regulation")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCPSC_Regulation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CPSC_Regulation")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Manufactured" SortExpression="Date_Manufactured">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Manufactured")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtDate_Manufactured" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Manufactured")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manufacturer" SortExpression="Manufacturer">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Manufacturer")%>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GreatGrizzlyConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Manufacturer]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="txtManufacturer" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GreatGrizzlyConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Manufacturer]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Manufacturer")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Date_Tested">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Tested")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate_Tested" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Tested")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test Lot ID" SortExpression="Test_Lot_ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Test_Lot_ID")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtTest_Lot_ID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Test_Lot_ID")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name Laboratory" SortExpression="Name_Laboratory">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Name_Laboratory")%>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GreatGrizzlyConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Laboratory]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="txtName_Laboratory" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GreatGrizzlyConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Laboratory]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name_Laboratory")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GreatGrizzlyConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Certificate] WHERE [CertificateID] = @CertificateID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Certificate] ([Customs_Entry], [Date_Certificate], [Invoice_Number], [Product_Number], [Product_Name], [Product_Category], [CPSC_Regulation], [Date_Manufactured], [Manufacturer], [Date_Tested], [Test_Lot_ID], [Name_Laboratory]) VALUES (@Customs_Entry, @Date_Certificate, @Invoice_Number, @Product_Number, @Product_Name, @Product_Category, @CPSC_Regulation, @Date_Manufactured, @Manufacturer, @Date_Tested, @Test_Lot_ID, @Name_Laboratory)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Certificate]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Certificate] SET [Customs_Entry] = @Customs_Entry, [Date_Certificate] = @Date_Certificate, [Invoice_Number] = @Invoice_Number, [Product_Number] = @Product_Number, [Product_Name] = @Product_Name, [Product_Category] = @Product_Category, [CPSC_Regulation] = @CPSC_Regulation, [Date_Manufactured] = @Date_Manufactured, [Manufacturer] = @Manufacturer, [Date_Tested] = @DatE_Tested, [Test_Lot_ID] = @Test_lot_ID, [Name_Laboratory] = @Name_Laboratory WHERE [CertificateID] = @CertificateID" FilterExpression="[CertificateID] like '{0}%' and [Customs_Entry] like '{0}%' and [Product_Number] like '{1}%' and [Product_Name] like '{2}%'">
            <FilterParameters> 
             <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtCertificateID_Filter" Name="CertificateID" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
             <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtCustoms_Entry_Filter" Name="Customs_Entry" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" /> 
             <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtProduct_Number_Filter" Name="Product_Name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" /> 
             <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtProduct_Name_Filter" Name="Product_Number" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />                    
            </FilterParameters>
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CertificateID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Customs_Entry" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Certificate" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Invoice_Number" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Product_Number" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Product_Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Product_Category" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CPSC_Regulation" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Manufactured" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Manufacturer" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Tested" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Test_Lot_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name_Laboratory" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Customs_Entry" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Certificate" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Invoice_Number" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Product_Number" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Product_Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Product_Category" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CPSC_Regulation" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Manufactured" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Manufacturer" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Tested" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Test_Lot_ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name_Laboratory" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the correct code:

```
FilterExpression="Convert(CertificateID , 'System.String') LIKE '{0}%'  and [Customs_Entry] like '{1}%' and [Product_Number] like '{2}%' and [Product_Name] like '{3}%'">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
CAST(Product_Number as varchar(10)) LIKE '{1}%'
```

you can change the 10 to whatever is appropriate.

EDIT
OK, then it is not getting to SQL server, have you tried

```
Convert(Product_Number , 'System.String') LIKE '{1}%'
```

Comment: I tried:  CAST(CertificateID as varchar(10)) LIKE '{1}%'

 but I get an error: The expression contains undefined function call CAST().

Comment: Ok, using Convert(Product_Number , 'System.String') LIKE '{1}%', I was able to load the page but when I go to search no matter what I type in any box the gridview returns nothing. but if they are blank the gridview populates all records. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did I answer your initial question?

Comment: well it gets rid of the error when i try loading the page but nothing displays now in the search results

Comment: you might want to change your "and"s to "or"s, but I think the initial problem has been corrected.

Comment: I got it working: I need to change the numbers in each Like '{1}%' starting from 0 then 1 then 2 then 3 for each like statement and it works now! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CONVERT ?

```
convert(varchar(length),[CertificateID]) like '{0}%'
```

Comment: I tried Convert but I get an error: The expression contains undefined function call varchar().

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
"Convert(" + Your Column Name + ",'System.String')" + " LIKE '*" + Searching Text + "*'"
```